# Blender quits automatically

Tags: modifiers

I got Multiple objects using (array) after that when i click anywhere in the blender window my blender quits automatically.[image]

Comment: Well, the first reason for quit / shutdown / crash while working with 4,5 million faces most likely are 4,5 million faces. Either find a way to work with less geometry somehow or find a way to increase RAM (or both maybe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all reduce the number of sub surf modifiers on the view to 1 or 2 but be sure not to get to 3 b'cos blender will be calculating alot of vertices or geometries and will definely quit on its own when its too much for it to calculate